# Continuity of eigenvector of zero eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvector, continuity

Wonder whether anyone has an idea on showing the following or to point out that it is not true:

Let $A(t) \in \Re^{n \times n}$ be differentiable over an interval $I$, and it has a zero eigenvalue for all $t \in I$.  Then, there exists an eigenvector $v(t)$ corresponding to the zero eigenvalue of $A(t)$ for $t \in I$ such that $v(t)$ is continuous a.e. on $I$.

Comment: This is not true, already for diagnonal $2\times 2$ matrices. But the question is not appropriate for MO.

Comment: For any diagonal $2 \times 2$ matrix which has a zero eigenvalue.  Suppose that its $(2,2)$ entry is zero.  The $0$-eigenvector $(0,1)$ is continuous for $t$ in $I$.  So I cannot say that it is not true.

Comment: Yes, now take a differentiable curve passing throught the matrix which is all zeroes, so that before it all but $(1, 1)$ entry is zero, and after it all but $(2, 2)$ entry is zero. Then you can't have a continuous eigenvalue at that point.

Comment: In the case of your example, there is a choice of which $0$-eigenvector to choose.  You can choose the $0$-eigenvector in such a way that it is continuous over $I$.  This is the key in this problem, which is the existence of an $0$-eigenvector $v(t)$ of $A(t)$ which is continuous over $I$.

Comment: Suppose $A(t) = \left( \begin{array}{cc} t & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ for $t \leq 0$ and $A(t) = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & t \end{array}\right)$ for $t > 0$.  This $A(t)$ is differentiable, and the $0$-eigenvector $(0, t)^T$ for $t \leq 0$ and $(t, 0)^T$ for $t > 0$ is continuous.

Comment: From the example that I gave above, at $t = 0$, it is a zero vector, which cannot be an eigenvector.  So based on the example, the question I would like to ask is whether there exists an $0$-eigenvector $v(t)$ that is continuous on $I$, except a set of zero measure.

Comment: Have a look to *Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators*, by Tosio Kato. I think it is free online.

Comment: Yes, I did look through the book, but I think the book considers more general situations.  I ask here to check whether researchers more familiar with the topic can provide a solution, which may be straightforward, and not too involved.  What I ask in the question is for special situation of zero eigenvalue which may have more straightforward solutions.

Comment: In your example, the vector is not an eigenvector for $t=0$, as eigenvectors are required to be nonzero. If you allow the zero vector the answer is obviously yes.

Comment: I have edited the question to ask for $0$-eigenvector $v(t)$ to be continuous a.e. on $I$, which is all I need.  Not necessarily continuous everywhere on $I$.

Comment: I am able to convince myself that there exists a continuous $0$-eigenvector $v(t)$ that is continuous over some non-singleton interval contained in $I$.  This holds only with the requirement that $A(t)$ is continuous on $I$.  Whether there exists of a continuous $0$-eigenvector $v(t)$ that is continuous a.e. on the whole interval $I$ is still unknown to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $I = [0,1]$. Construct the set $A(t) = {\rm{Diag}}(a_{1,1}(t), a_{2,2}(t)) \in \Re^{2 \times 2}$ as follows:

First, let the set $E \subset I$ be the fat Cantor set.

For each $k \geq 1$ in the construction of the set $E$, let the intervals removed at the $k^{th}$ step be $(c_{k,i}, d_{k,i})$, $i = 1, \dotsc, 2^{k-1}$.

For $c < d$, define continuous $f_{c,d}(t)$ and $g_{c,d}(t)$ for $t \in (c,d)$ by
\begin{align*}
f_{c,d}(t) & = \begin{cases}
                \frac{2c+d}{d-c} - \frac{3}{d-c}t  & , c < t \leq \frac{2c + d}{3} \\
                0 & , \frac{2c+d}{3} \leq t \leq \frac{2d + c}{3} \\
                -\frac{2d+c}{d-c}  + \frac{3}{d-c}t  & , \frac{2d + c}{3} \leq t < d,
                \end{cases} \\
    & &             \\
g_{c,d}(t) & =  \begin{cases}
               0 & , c < t \leq \frac{2c + d}{3} \\
                -\frac{2(2c+d)}{d-c}  + \frac{6}{d-c}t  & , \frac{2c+d}{3} \leq t \leq \frac{c+d}{2} \\
                 \frac{2(2d+c)}{3}   - \frac{6}{d-c}t  & , \frac{c+d}{2} \leq t \leq \frac{2d+c}{3} \\
                   0  & , \frac{2d+c}{3} \leq t < d.
            \end{cases}
\end{align*}

Define for $t \in I$, $a_{1,1}(t)$, $a_{2,2}(t)$ by
\begin{align*}
a_{1,1}(t) & = \begin{cases}
                    1 & , t \in E \\
                    f_{c_{k,i},d_{k,i}}(t) & , t \in (c_{k,i},d_{k,i}), i = 1, \dotsc, 2^{k-1}, k \geq 1,
                    \end{cases} \\
                    \\
& &  \\
a_{2,2}(t) & = \begin{cases}
                    0 & , t \in E \\
                    g_{c_{k,i},d_{k,i}}(t) & , t \in (c_{k,i},d_{k,i}), i = 1, \dotsc, 2^{k-1}, k \geq 1.
                    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

We have $a_{1,1}(t)$ and $a_{2,2}(t)$ are continuous, but can be easily adapted to be differentiable, on $I$.  Furthermore, define $F \subset I \setminus E$ to be such that
\begin{equation*}
F = \bigcup_{k \geq 1} \bigcup_{1 \leq i \leq 2^{k-1}} \left[\frac{2 c_{k,i} + d_{k,i}}{3}, \frac{2d_{k,i}+c_{k,i}}{3} \right].
\end{equation*}

For $t \in E$, $0$-eigenvectors of $A(t)$ are of the form $[0, \ast]^T$; for $t \in F$, $0$-eigenvectors of $A(t)$ are of the form $[\ast, 0]^T$; for $t \in I \backslash (E \cup F)$, $0$-eigenvectors of $A(t)$ are of the form $[0, \ast]^T$.

For any $t \in E$.  Given any open neighborhood of $t$ in $I$, there exists $t_1 \in F$ in the neighborhood, we see then that any $0$-eigenvector $v(t)$ of $A(t)$ cannot be continuous at $t \in E$, where $m(E) > 0$.